# vertical navigation bar using CSS bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a vertical navigation bar, I am using bootstrap 3.0,

I searched for any example and could only find [this](http://d.alistapart.com/horizdropdowns/horizontal2.htm)

```
<ul> 
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#">About</a> 
   <ul> 
  <li><a href="#">History</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Team</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Offices</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</li> 
<li><a href="#">Services</a> 
  <ul> 
  <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Internet 
        Marketing</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Domain Names</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Broadband</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a> 
  <ul> 
  <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">France</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">USA</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Australia</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</li> 
</ul>
```

But I dont exactly want this, what i want is something like this
[image]

I am new to CSS and could find anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/CF5PQ/2/

Can anyone pls help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I searched for any example and could only find" yeah sure! There is navigation examples like in every other website in world :)

Comment: @Hardy i want something similar like the image can u pls show the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started.. You have to style your 
lists like this:

```
ul li {
  /* styles for first level */ 
  background: #fff; /* white bg */

}

ul li ul li {
  /* styles for second level */
  background: #ccc; /* grey bg */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeking for multi columned menus as far as I understand You can get it with some tweaks.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click Me!</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu multi-column">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Top Left</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bottom Left</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Top Right</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bottom Right</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And you have to add some rules for getting multi columned visibility

```
 .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
        width: 250px; /*Set manually according to menu text and column count*/
}

.dropdown-menu.multi-column .dropdown-menu {
        display: block !important;
        position: static !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        border: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        min-width:100px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5NfxT/1/

This is for two columned menu. For more you have to change divs' classes "`col-md-*`" and also width value of `.dropdown-menu .multi-column` rule.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
```

As you know, Bootstrap uses grid system which divides screen into 12 columns. for 3 column menu you have to use `col-md-4`, and for 4 columned menu use `col-md-3`.

Another point, if you increase the column count, you have to widen the dropdown menu pad as well.